# How to access my site as http://www.blah.com and http://blah.com

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I own a domain on GoDaddy, let's say blah.com. And i point an A record @ to my server IP, let's say 123.123.123.123.

The GoDaddy panel already have a CNAME record www wich points to @.

I suppose that under this configuration, i could acces blah.com as http://blah.com and http://www.blah.com.

However, only http://www.blah.com works ok, because http://blah.com shows me a GoDaddy page.

What aim doing wrong?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they also hosting your server? You have to properly configure your web server to handle each request accordingly. You got the DNS part correct. Now configure your webserver.

Comment: No they don't. I will try configuring the apache Virtual Host section.